# Receber caractere em C

Tags: c, pascal, funções, clipper

Como eu faço uma função em `C` que seja igual à função `Readkey` do `Pascal` ou igual à função `Lastkey` do velho `Clipper`? Quero receber apenas um caractere em separado para cada tecla pressionada. Criar menus, receber tecla <kbd>ESC</kbd>,  etc. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: O equivalente do Readkey do Pascal é o Inkey do Clipper, e não o Lastkey. Qual dos dois comportamentos você deseja?

Answer (score 0):

Em C precisas duma biblioteca externa para fazer isso. O padrão da linguagem não define uma maneira para isso. Uma biblioteca externa que apresenta essa funcionalidade é a [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses); deve haver outras, mas não conheço.

Exemplo tirado de [NCURSES Programming HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) *e com algumas alterações a meu gosto*:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(void) {    
    initscr();                /* Start curses mode              */
    printw("Hello, World!");  /* Print Hello. World!            */
    refresh();                /* Print it on to the real screen */
    getch();                  /* Wait for user input            */
    endwin();                 /* End curses mode                */
    return 0;
}
```